# Variable in hugo theme not working as expected

Tags: hugo

I got an issue recently and I can’t resolve it on my own.

In my code `$locale` returns current language, the default is `en`

```
{{ $locale := .Site.Language.Lang }}
```

following that, I checked that outputs of two following expressions

```
{{ (index .Site.Data $locale).nav.sidebar.navItems }}
```

```
{{ (index .Site.Data "en").nav.sidebar.navItems }}
```

return correctly the same data.
**sidebar.json** file looks like this:

```
{
  "navItems": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Parent",
      "url": "/",
      "parent": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Child",
      "url": "/",
      "parent": {
        "id": 1
      }
    },
...
  ]
}
```

In code below

```
{{ $menus := (index .Site.Data $locale).nav.sidebar.navItems }}
{{ $mainMenus := where $menus "parent" nil }}
```

I get error `error calling where: can't iterate over <nil>`
but when I change it for

```
{{ $menus := (index .Site.Data "en").nav.sidebar.navItems }}
```

result is as expected.
I don't want to have languages hardcoded due to other languages I will use in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I created such workaround:

```
{{ $locale := .Site.Language.Lang }}
{{ $menus := (index .Site.Data $locale).nav.footer.navItems }}
{{ $mainMenus := slice }}
{{ $subMenus := slice }}
{{ range $menus }}
  {{ if (isset .parent "id") }}
    {{ $subMenus = $subMenus | append . }}
  {{ else }}
    {{ $mainMenus = $mainMenus | append . }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

but I'm still confused why `locale` variable didn't work with `where` function.